# Why is my Lead Source not mapping over to Account & giving me an error?

Tags: lead-conversion, field-mapping

When trying to convert a Lead with a Lead Source set, It will not convert and I receive the following error:
Error: Your lead is missing a field mapping for the Account.Lead Source field. For help, talk with your admin or see Map Custom Lead Fields for Lead Conversion in Salesforce Help.

I'm not sure why this is happening since the Lead Source is automatically mapped over to the Account (Lead) Source field and doesn't need to be set. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the standard Lead Source field on the Lead object is not mapped automatically to the Account Source field on the Account object when converting a lead.

Refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214805&language=en_US&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) help link from Salesforce which  will  show you how to use custom fields and Workflow Rules to accomplish this mapping.

Comment: I agree that this is a valid answer, though this may be one of the only times that I would suggest a trigger-based solution instead of a declarative-based solution. It just has so many moving parts and won't be changed, most likely.
Solid answer, so I'm upvoting it. I just wish Salesforce would have supplied a sample trigger to do it in one step!